# Sharepoint list column name change

Tags: list-form

We changed the name of a custom column in a list however it stills shows up in the edit properties with the orginal column name. Does anyone know how we can update the properties form to show the udated column name?

thanks,
Kim

Answer (score 3):

Did you change the column name through List Properties? Is this a site column?

The Properties Form should show the Display name for the column (I quickly tested in SharePoint 2007 and works ok).